# Run functions in order based on condition

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise

I have a function that returns some data based on conditions but in my `else` I want to call 2 functions but I want the first one to run before the second one does. I think I can add a `promise` here but I am not sure how to do that.

My code:

```
result.data.table_fields.forEach((d) => {
    if (d.type != "connected_field") {
      // do something
    } else {
      getAllTables({ query: tables(dev_id) }).then((res) => {
        if (d.label in res) {
          // do something
        } else {
            getAllTables({ query: tables(prod_org) }).then((prod) => {
               if (d.label in prod) {
                  //do something
               } else console.log(`${d.label} DOES NOT EXIST}`);
            });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Is there a way to do this without nesting the functions. I need to check if the value first exists in `dev` before checking `prod`.

Comment: `promise.then((res) => { body })` can generally be rewritten as `let res = await promise; body;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the function you're calling in `forEach` `async`, then you can use `await` inside it instead of nested `.then()`.

```
result.data.table_fields.forEach(async(d) => {
  if (d.type != "connected_field") {
    // do something
  } else {
    let res = await getAllTables({query: tables(dev_id)});
    if (d.label in res) {
      // do something
    } else {
      let prod = await getAllTables({query: tables(prod_org)});
      if (d.label in prod) {
        //do something
      } else {
        console.log(`${d.label} DOES NOT EXIST}`);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

However, this does lots of repeated `getAllTables()` queries in the loop. You might want to do both of them just once, then check whether `d.label` is in either of the results in the loop.

```
(async() => {
  let dev = await getAllTables({
    query: tables(dev_id)
  });
  let prod = await getAllTables({
    query: tables(prod_org)
  });

  result.data.table_fields.forEach((d) => {
    if (d.type != "connected_field") {
      // do something
    } else if (d.label in dev) {
      // do something
    } else if (d.label in prod) {
      //do something
    } else {
      console.log(`${d.label} DOES NOT EXIST}`);
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: …and also one should not pass an `async` function as a callback to `forEach`, so the second snippet is definitely preferable

Comment: @Bergi Why should you not pass an `async` callback? I don't see a problem with it if its effects are local to the array's item, and a rejection is insignificant.

Comment: @OskarGrosser [because it does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572), and rejections are not insignificant, they crash your entire nodejs process